# Custom Commands for Minecraft using python and mcpi

Tags: python, minecraft

I've just started with [mcpi](https://pypi.org/project/mcpi/) and I want to have custom commands to capture chat posts starting with `/`.

How can I use custom commands to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you able to add some examples of commands you have already tried or the code related to your question?

Comment: I dont know how to create any command. My Problem is that I don't even know wether mcpi supports using minecrafts command system. I want to know how to register commands.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, mcpi does not support a command system. However writing your own should not be too difficult if mcpi supports on message send events, not sure what it would be called in the API but I would guess it would be like that. Anyways I have a few ideas on how to implement it, some better than others.

1.
Check if the message "intercepted" or  received has a / prepended to the message, if so, remove the prefix, and split the string by spaces. However this offers some, notable issues. For one, the code would get extremely messy, seriously messy as you'd have to handle every single argument, on it's own. Secondly, it removes the possibility of "escaped" arguments in which you can say give an argument that is a string and is surrounded by double quotes and can contain spaces. This would fail to work as it would split regardless of whether the space is within quotation marks, and doesn't acknowledge them. These are the limitations of this relatively basic implementation. Hence, Idea #2.

2. I use this implementation for my argument parser for a helper library for a Golang Discord bot library. The jist comes down to checking for the prefix again, remove it. Then check if the length of the message string is not 0. If it is 0, ignore the message, otherwise do the following:
   Have a regular expression for identifying arguments, be it escaped or non-escaped. Find all matches within the string, (ignoring non-matches, making extra white-space not an issue... yey!). Store all the matches in an "Argument" object, which would have some helper methods for parsing the string to say a float, or an integer. (Cleaner code!!). Finally, put all of the arguments in an array, or linked list, just as long as they're in order, and work from there. If you need a reference (It's written in Golang, but it's not really a complex language), check out that helper library I wrote: https://github.com/32Bites/wetgear .

Sorry if this is hard to read, let me know if you need any help or anything, regardless I wish you the best.

Comment: Not sure if it is mcpi or minecrafts API but i've tried printing out writen messages and ones with a slash were not shown but it's probably just mcpi not showing it. However I've started with Java now since I think it contains full support for minecaft's API. Anyways I'd be happy if you know anything more about python support for minecraft plugins since im way more comfortable with python than with java.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own. Here is a example of something I have done in the past.

https://gamebanana.com/scripts/10865 - link to full code

```
from mcpi.minecraft import Minecraft
from mcpi import entity


mc = Minecraft.create(address="0.0.0.0", port=4711)

players_ids = mc.getPlayerEntityIds()
print(len(players_ids), " entities available.")
number = len(players_ids)
mc.postToChat(  "%s entities available." %number)

for id in players_ids:
    mc.postToChat("Entity : %s" %id)


def playerEntity1(player):
    #from mcLogListener import on_press
    import time
    from classSummon import ArrowTrap, DiamondTrap, EnderWarrior, FallingSky
    from jutsu import amenotejikara, allMightyPush, stillWater, lavaFlow, portalDoor, oakPlank, darkMatter, fireAShot
    from mcpi.minecraft import Minecraft

    
    mc = Minecraft.create(address="0.0.0.0", port=4711)
    #custom commands
    chatPost = "0"
    while True:
        
        for chatPost in mc.entity.pollChatPosts(players_ids[0]):
            if chatPost.message.lower() == "6":
                mc.postToChat("Amenotejikara is activated")
                chatPost = "6"
            elif chatPost.message.lower() == "7":
                mc.postToChat("All Mighty Push is activated")
                chatPost = "7"
            elif chatPost.message.lower() == "1":
                mc.postToChat("Water Pool jutsu!")
                chatPost = "1"
            elif chatPost.message.lower() == "2":
                mc.postToChat("Flowing Lava Jutsu!")
                chatPost = "2"
            elif chatPost.message.lower() == "3":
                mc.postToChat("Portal Summoning Jutsu")
                chatPost = "3"
            elif chatPost.message.lower() == "4":
                mc.postToChat("Oak Wood Jutsu")
                chatPost = "4"
            elif chatPost.message.lower() == "5":
                mc.postToChat("Obsidian Forbidin Jutsu")
                chatPost = "5"
            elif chatPost.message.lower() == '8':
                mc.postToChat("Fireball Jutsu")
                chatPost = "8"
            elif chatPost.message.lower() == '11':
                mc.postToChat("Arrow Glass Prism Jutsu")
                chatPost = "11"
            elif chatPost.message.lower() == '12':
                mc.postToChat("Diamond Prism Jutsu")
                chatPost = "12"
            elif chatPost.message.lower() == '13':
                mc.postToChat("Ender Tools Jutsu")
                chatPost = "13"
            elif chatPost.message.lower() == '14':
                mc.postToChat("Mighty Sand Trap")
                chatPost = "14"
            elif chatPost.message.lower() == '0':
                mc.postToChat("test")
                chatPost = "0"

                '''Listener for arrow shots'''   
            
        for blockhit in mc.entity.pollProjectileHits(players_ids[0]):
            pos = blockhit.pos
            x = pos.x
            y = pos.y
            z = pos.z
            
            if chatPost == "6":
                amenotejikara(players_ids[0])#Teleporting Arrow 
            elif chatPost == "7":
                allMightyPush(players_ids[0])#Air Arrow
            elif chatPost == "8":
                fireAShot(players_ids[0])#Fire Arrow
            elif chatPost == "11":
                trapArrow = ArrowTrap(x, y, z, 3)#Trap arrow class
                trapArrow.build()#Pyramid1
                trapArrow.bottom()#Pyramid2
            elif chatPost == "14":
                fArrow = FallingSky(x, y, z, 1)#FallingSky class
                fArrow.garvelPyramidHole()#Mob pit
                fArrow.garvelPyramidTop()#Falling sand
                fArrow.garvelPyramid()#falling sand
                fArrow.garvelPyramidBottom()#falling sand
            else:
                mc.events.clearAll()

                '''Sword block Listener'''
        for blockhit in mc.entity.pollBlockHits(players_ids[0]):
            pos = blockhit.pos
            x = pos.x
            y = pos.y
            z = pos.z
            
            if chatPost == "1":
                stillWater(players_ids[0])#Water block sword block
            elif chatPost == "2":
                lavaFlow(players_ids[0])#Lava block sword block
            elif chatPost == "3":
                portalDoor(players_ids[0])# 1*3 nether portal block
            elif chatPost == "4":
                oakPlank(players_ids[0])#Wood block sword block
                
            elif chatPost == "5":
                darkMatter(players_ids[0])#Obsidian block sword block
            elif chatPost == "12":
                glassDiamond = DiamondTrap(x,y,z,3) #DiamondTrap class
                glassDiamond.buildB()
            elif chatPost == "13":
                endLoot = EnderWarrior(x, y, z, 2)#EnderWarrior class
                endLoot.enderOre()
                endLoot.enderPumpkin()
                endLoot.crafting()
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There *is* `pollChatPosts()` but it hangs when called, however I've actually succeeded in making a commands client.
I'm currently working on updating it because the code is spaghetti but it does work with MCPI-Reborn: Extended at the moment, I also made a mod (primarily by copying someone else' code) that will not post a message to chat if it starts with `/`.
This is useful because my command client works by launching MCPI-Reborn through a subprocess taking action when a messages is printed (such as `[CHAT] <username> /`)

Here's the link to my Github repo: https://github.com/Red-exe-Engineer/MCPI-slash-commands

Just for clarification and to prevent skimming, ****THE CODE WILL BE UPDATED SOON™****

Hope this helps :D